# 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'complie'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting error `'Sequential' object has no attribute 'complie'` while using `keras` under `tensorflow`.

I checked on `git` and came to know that this was an existing bug but has been rectified after making changes in vis_utils.py(removing model.model from below block of code).

```
if isinstance(model, Sequential):
    if not model.built:
      model.build()
    layers = model.layers
```

I tried to install `keras` standalone and again I am getting the same error.

`Tensorflow`version is`1.10` and `keras` version is `2.2.2`
The `python` version I am using is `3.6`

Comment: its compile, not complie, this is just a misspelling problem.

Comment: Right now, I just logged in to remove this question due to my mind blowing error.Thanks Matias, you got this in first look which I didnt in 100 efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting error 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'complie' while using keras under tensorflow.

Its Not "complie" its "compile" change it and it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).